# Cordova to Android studio error malformed \uxxxx encoding

Tags: java, android, cordova, android-studio

I want to import my Cordova project to Android Studio.
But when on `Grandle Sync`, this error is shown -

```
malformed \uxxxx encoding
```

The error part is:

```
def addSigningProps(propsFilePath, signingConfig) {
    def propsFile = file(propsFilePath)
    def props = new Properties()
    propsFile.withReader { reader ->
        props.load(reader) //this line is the error (line 290)
    }
```

The entire Gradle file is available here: https://pastebin.com/66vVKHzG

How to solve this ?

Comment: was the cordova project built for android platform and was it working fine without any errors?

Comment: @pro_cheats yes there no errors

Answer (score 4):

The error is caused in android build when we use `\usr\<blah>` i.e a `\`(backslash) instead of `/`(forward slash) in directory structure. The parser will see it as an escape character!!

I still don't know from where that `\` is getting used from your Cordova Project. You need to figure that out based on what functionalities you are doing and where you are using file system.

According to your code `propsFilePath` might be having a `\` which is causing this error.

Reference - https://coderanch.com/t/107014/Malformed-uxxxx-encoding-error

Comment: Thank you but I don't see this in the gradle file

Comment: I've had the same exact problem malformed \uxxxx encoding, but when trying to build a flutter app, as it turns out the key.propterties file contains a file location with \ (backslash) because I'm on windows, I switched to / (forward slash) and the problem is no more, so thank you