# Error on building QT Android build with Gradle : Malformed \uxxxx encoding

Tags: qt, build.gradle

For automated build generation, scripts are written to automate and generate QT Android build with gradle.

The build step fails at the last step.
The command given is

> C:\Qt\5.10.1\android_armv7\bin\androiddeployqt.exe --input
>   C:/Users/user1/Desktop/Sources/Software/build_android/android-libTestApp.so-deployment-settings.json
>   --output android_lisha --debug --android-platform android-28 --jdk "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_65" --gradle

Error observed is:

> <-------------> 0% INITIALIZING [0s]> Evaluating
>   settings<-------------> 0% INITIALIZING [0s]> Evaluating
>   settings<-------------> 0% INITIALIZING [0s]> Evaluating
>   settings<-------------> 0% CONFIGURING [0s]> Loading
>   projects<-------------> 0% CONFIGURING [0s]> Loading
>   projects<-------------> 0% CONFIGURING [0s]> root
>   project<-------------> 0% CONFIGURING [0s]> root
>   project<-------------> 0% CONFIGURING [0s]> root
>   project<-------------> 0% CONFIGURING [0s]> root
>   project<-------------> 0% CONFIGURING [0s]> root
>   project<-------------> 0% CONFIGURING [1s]> root
>   project<-------------> 0% CONFIGURING [1s]> root project > Resolve
>   dependencies of :classpath<-------------> 0% CONFIGURING [1s]> root
>   project > Resolve dependencies of :classpath<-------------> 0%
>   CONFIGURING [1s]> root project<-------------> 0% CONFIGURING [1s]>
>   root project<-------------> 0% CONFIGURING [1s]> root
>   project<-------------> 0% CONFIGURING [1s]> root
>   project<-------------> 0% CONFIGURING [1s]> root
>   project<-------------> 0% CONFIGURING [1s]> root project
>   **FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.**
>
> **Where: Build file 'C:\Users\user1\Desktop\Sources\Software\build_android\android_lisha\build.gradle'
>   line: 19
>   * What went wrong: A problem occurred evaluating root project 'android_lisha'.
>
> > Failed to apply plugin [id 'com.android.application']
> >     Malformed \uxxxx encoding.**

Classpath used in build.gradle file:

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.0'
```

Distribution URL in gradle.wrapper.properties file:

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.9-all.zip
```

QT Creator IDE version : 4.6.1

I have checked the related links in stack overflow like 
i) [Cordova to Android studio error malformed \uxxxx encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44959885/cordova-to-android-studio-error-malformed-uxxxx-encoding)
ii) https://github.com/googlesamples/unity-jar-resolver/issues/92.
Above links did not help much.

Can anyone please help in figuring out the issue.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you are using a version of the Android SDK and/or NDK that is too new. I had a lot of trouble getting Qt to compile Android apps until I switched to known good versions of the Android SDK and NDK, then locked those down by copying them to their own static folder for use with Qt so that Android Studio doesn't have any chance of updating them to introduce new problems with my Qt Android builds.

From what I can see in your build failure, you're using build SDK android-28 and gradle 4.9.

From my working Qt Android builds, I'm using build SDK android-25 and gradle 3.4.

The Qt documentation (https://wiki.qt.io/Android) specifically mentions that you must use Android NDK r10, as later versions are known to have problems. You can download the old NDK r10 here:
https://developer.android.com/ndk/downloads/older_releases

The Qt documentation doesn't seem to list any specific Android SDK version to use, but I know from experience that I've had build troubles in the past when I was using the very latest Android Studio updated SDKs. Find one that works, then copy the SDK out so that you can keep your Qt Android builds working even when Google breaks things in the future.